# Windows Lock Screen display text programmatically C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Sample Screenshot - Spotify Lock-Screen information

[image]

How can I display information on the lock screen? Like Spotify does.

EDIT:
Can see question is duplicated, so, the question now is - how Spotify do this?
For Windows 10.
Using WPF/UWP/WinForms whatever.
If it is possible only using other language/hacks - always something.

Comment: I don't understand downvotes... I was trying to google it, but can't find any tutorial or example.

Comment: @Rhonin, me neither. It might be that there are many ways to do that, which means your question is "too broad", or something like that. Who knows? In any case you need to add relevant tags with operative system and version, also is this Winforms, WPF, etc?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-lockscreen

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/08/05/detailed-lock-screen-status-for-windows-10/  Its a type of Live Tile.

Comment: does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-lockscreen and a code example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Lock-screen-apps-sample-9843dc3a

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Output:**

[image: LockScreen ScreenShoot]

My code to run example (in button event, it won't start while application is starting):

```
TileContent content = new TileContent()
{
    Visual = new TileVisual()
    {
        LockDetailedStatus1 = "Meeting with Thomas",
        LockDetailedStatus2 = "11:00 AM - 12:30 PM",
        LockDetailedStatus3 = "Studio F",

        TileWide = new TileBinding() { }
    }
};
var notification = new TileNotification(content.GetXml());
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);
```

**Followed:**

1. [Detailed-lock-screen-status-for-windows-10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/08/05/detailed-lock-screen-status-for-windows-10/)
2. [Quickstart-sending-a-local-tile-notification-in-windows-10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/10/05/quickstart-sending-a-local-tile-notification-in-windows-10/)

Thanks for help to people in comments for the links above!