# C# custom windows 10 lock screen text

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, uwp

I have some trouble with the Windows 10 Lock Screen. I want to show their my "own text" programmatically with C# (like Spotify)

I tried something with UWP, I managed to get normal toast messages, but I couldn't display any kind of text or badge on the lock screen.

I want something like on this image:
[screenhot of windows lock screen while playing music in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edpj7.png)

Thanks for any kind of help

**Edit:**
Code which I tried but it didn't work. When I click on a button this happens:

```
ToastContent content = new ToastContent()
            {
                //Duration = ToastDuration.Long,
                Scenario = ToastScenario.Reminder,
                Visual = new ToastVisual()
                {
                    BindingGeneric = new ToastBindingGeneric()
                    {
                        Attribution = new ToastGenericAttributionText()
                        {
                            Text = "Hello World"
                        }
                    }
                },
                Actions = new ToastActionsCustom()
                {
                    Buttons = {
                new ToastButton ("mycontent", "myargs")
            }
                }
            };
            var notification = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(notification);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display UWP control on lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157662/display-uwp-control-on-lock-screen)

Comment: @Jesse no, not really. I saw this post but it didnt help me. I am also new to all this, thats why it is so difficult for me to understand this.

Comment: What are your tries? We need code to debug or fix, not question to code from zero.

Comment: @wpferr19 I will vote to reopen but at this stage, I think you better make a new question.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli i will make a new question, thank you for your help